# Assign path to variable which does not exist

Tags: bash, shell, variable

In an effort of keeping things DRY, I am trying to assign a path to a variable that may not exist and have the following script which returns:

> /apps/tmp: No such file or directory

```
#!/bin/bash

$WORKDIR="/apps/tmp"

if [ -d $WORKDIR ]; then 
    rm -rf $WORKDIR
fi
```

Is this possible or what work around is there?

Comment: I'd expect the error to be _myscript: 3: =/apps/tmp: No such file or directory_

Comment: It may have done, I remember extracting the main context as I didn't think it was important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create new variable, you are not using dollar `$` sign. Just do:

```
WORKDIR="/apps/tmp"
```

Comment: Coming from various languages, this always catches me out. Many thanks

Comment: Yes. I know. Especially from PHP the syntax is just in the back of your head. You are welcome. And of course, welcome to Unix & Linux!